# Typescript types HTTP request Rest API

Tags: node.js, typescript

So, I'm having some issue with my code because some types not specified and I don't know what type should I use.

````
  const ***connectionOptions*** = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Basic ' + new Buffer(this.config.USERNAME + ':' + this.config.PASSWORD).toString('base64')
    },
    host: 'http://lpr.houstonhidta.net',
    path: '/live/alarm',
    port: 8099
  };

  const ***request*** = http.request(connectionOptions, (***response***) => {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', (***chunk***) => {
      return response._read;
    });
  });```

Types missing for : <br/>
connectionOptions<br/>
request<br/>
response<br/>
chunk<br/>
````

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what http library you are using, but generally the following options exist:

1. The library you use ships types. In this case you can possibly just dive into the source of this library and find the correct types.
2. The types are shipped in a `@types/foo` package (foo being the name of the package you are using). In this case, you can find the types also by reading the source of this package.
3. Neither are available, so you need to come up with your own types. This isn't that difficult.

For example, the first object you specified might have this type:

```
type ConnectionOptions = {
  headers: {
    [s: string]: string
  },
  host: string,
  path: string,
  port: number
}
```

Comment: I'm using require('http');

Comment: Ah I didn't recognize it. You probably need to run `npm install -D @types/node`

Comment: Not works. Should have some types for this guys, don't?

Comment: For connectionOptions I think is object the type

Comment: @AndreMoraes take a look at the source of the @types/node package to find all the types you need. For your code sample you can omit the type for connectionOptions.

Comment: Not everything needs a type because types can often be inferred. However, i think this is the type: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/http.d.ts#L70